# Are there any techniques that quantify the importance/signification of individual attribute values of a particular data point?

Tags: data-mining, feature-selection

Are there any techniques that quantize the importance of individual attribute values in a particular data point, in terms of the attribute's overall importance/signification/contribution to the uniqueness of the data point (uniqueness with respect to the whole data set).

I'm not entirely sure if I've put it perfectly. Forgive if I'm not perfect in my presentation. I've looked up a lot on the web, particularly in Google Scholar, but couldn't find anything relevant while I'm running out of keywords I can think of. Please let me know if anything similar to what I've written exists.

Comment: Does the definition of [multivariate outlier](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Multivariate_outlier) suit your purpose? Here's a quote from the linked source: "Multivariate outliers...are cases with an unusual combination of scores on different variables." A univariate outlier would be an unusually unique **single** data point with respect to the whole **distribution of that variable**, whereas a multivariate outlier would be a case with an unusual combination of **multiple** data points with respect to **multiple variables' distributions, potentially including the entire data set**.

Comment: It sure seems close, but my query is about ways to use the above end in mind to quantize every data point in a dataset and then retain the knowledge. Finding outliers could be one application of such knowledge aggregation.

Comment: "Uniqueness of the datapoint" and "retain the knowledge" are pretty vague.  It would help to have a clearer description or at least a good example of what you're looking for.

Comment: @whuber I am also looking for something similar in the domain of GP regression or even regular regression. I want to minimize the number of collected datapoints so to discard the datapoint such that we "retain the knowledge" or the hypothesis/model dont change significantly after discarding points. Is there standard technique out there?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that you are asking about methods how to measure the **influence of
points on analysis.**
Perhaps the most usefull tool for this is the `influence.measures` function in R.
This function can compute some of the regression (leave-one-out deletion)
diagnostics for linear and generalized linear models.

```
# example data
my.data<-data.frame(ID=seq(1:9), x=c(rnorm(9)), y=c(rnorm(9)))
plot(my.data$x, my.data$y)
text(my.data$x, my.data$y, labels=my.data$ID, pos=2)
abline(my.regression, col="red")
```

let's do a simple regression to look for possible trends

```
my.regression<-lm(y ~ x, data=my.data)
```

As you can see the result is non-significant (points come to random normal distribution so no surprise)

```
summary(my.regression)

    Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.3853     0.4313   0.894    0.401
x             0.1161     0.4333   0.268    0.797

Residual standard error: 1.201 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01015,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.1313 
F-statistic: 0.07175 on 1 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.7965
```

Now let's do the identification of **points which if deleted the significance of regression will change**

```
influence.measures(my.regression)

Influence measures of
     lm(formula = y ~ x, data = my.data) :

   dfb.1_   dfb.x   dffit cov.r  cook.d   hat inf
1  0.1116  0.1027  0.1913 1.512 0.02066 0.156    
2  0.0576 -0.0110  0.0587 1.525 0.00200 0.115    
3 -1.6255  1.9686 -2.1913 1.270 1.76227 0.576   *
4  0.0268  0.0655  0.0856 1.847 0.00426 0.268    
5 -0.3887  0.0281 -0.4084 1.027 0.07968 0.112    
6 -0.2765 -0.2216 -0.4456 1.126 0.09725 0.148    
7  0.0812  0.1249  0.1858 1.632 0.01969 0.203    
8  0.0444  0.0168  0.0570 1.538 0.00189 0.122    
9  2.1227 -1.9630  2.4707 0.173 1.06006 0.301   *
```

So, if you delete point number 3 or 9 than you may expect change in significance of regression.

For details see *R documentation* to `influence.measures`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as in my original question, I'm trying to know if there are techniques that can in some manner quantitatively say something about the relative importance of attribute values of any particular data point taken into consideration.

Comment: @Ketan how would you define "relative importance of attribute values"?  Shouldnt it depend on your choice of how you are "defining" importance?